# Getting at ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the test on a user model - the issue is right at the bottom but can't work out why its going wrong despite the reference to the specific line.

```
    require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = " "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should be present" do
    @user.email = " "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should not be too long" do
    @user.name = "a" * 51
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example.foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      assert_not @user.valid?
    end

   #this is the line 36 its complaining about... 
  test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
    duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
    end
  end  
end
```

My /models/user.rb is as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }  
validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

This is the error I'm getting but really can't work out how I've got the wrong number of arguements, especially as this is copied from Chapter 6 of Michael Hartls book - been trawling the internet for about a day now and simply can;t work it out?

```
ERROR["test_email_validation_should_reject_invalid_addresses", UserTest, 0.0499
93779]                                                                         
 test_email_validation_should_reject_invalid_addresses#UserTest (0.05s)        
ArgumentError:         ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)      
            test/models/user_test.rb:36:in `test'                              
            test/models/user_test.rb:36:in `block in <class:UserTest>'         
        test/models/user_test.rb:36:in `test'                                  
        test/models/user_test.rb:36:in `block in <class:UserTest>'
```

Comment: You seem to have an extra `end` in there after `assert_not duplicate_user.valid?`. As pointed out below, that `end` belongs to the test before it.

Comment: you are missing end end for `test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but neither of those suggestions was a fix - I tried end,end and end,end on the last 2 blocks plus other combinations...just don;t get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `end`s are mixed up a bit in your last 2 tests. The fully revised file below:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = " "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should be present" do
    @user.email = " "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should not be too long" do
    @user.name = "a" * 51
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example.foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      assert_not @user.valid?
    end  # end of each block
  end    # end of test block

  test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
    duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
  end    # end of test block
end      # end of class
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I have and I am still getting the same error?!

Comment: OK maybe 12 hours of this has driven me a little tired. I have now got this to work with your explanation and thanks for showing why the 'ends' were inserted as they have been. This can be a frustrating process!!

Comment: No problem. I remember first learning Rails not too long ago — I know that frustration, but it's worth it in the end. Cheers!